# PLSQL To read specific tag values from Binary file (here it is xml) and to store then in cursor and display them

Tags: plsql, cursor, blob, procedure, ref-cursor

I am trying to read and print one of the specific tag values from BLOB file. In my case, BLOB data is stored in database and the content inside binary file is of XML but binary type.

I am able to get only first value of one of the tag  which is repetitive.
DATA_VALUE is the column name.

```
SELECT dbms_output.put_line(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( dbms_lob.substr(DATA_VALUE, 8,DBMS_LOB.INSTR(DATA_VALUE,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('<MATNR>000000000'),1,1)+17)) FROM NES.WLI_DB WHERE ID = '0000000331756259';
```

Result:- 12268646

How can i list all the values of  tag without duplicates and list them so that i can use them as input to some other SQL query?

I tried using iterative FOR loop by fetching the BLOB content into Cursor but i am able to get only first occurrence of  tag.

As the lines will be more and more by each of such files, is there any possibility to recursively read and display required information without duplicate values?

Here is my BLOB data which is stored in DATA_VALUE column of my table:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<_-GLB_-OGTX_DESADV01_CUST_ASN xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <E1EDK08 SEGMENT="1">
            <WAERK>AUD</WAERK>
            <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDK08_01 SEGMENT="1">
                <REPEAT_COUNT>01</REPEAT_COUNT>
                <TOTAL_PALLETS> 25</TOTAL_PALLETS>
                <TOTAL_SHPD_QTY>1735.000</TOTAL_SHPD_QTY>
                <TOTAL_ORD_QTY>1735.000</TOTAL_ORD_QTY>
                <VOLUM>29300.964</VOLUM>
                <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                <SEAL01>9428603</SEAL01>
                <CHARFIELD1>CS</CHARFIELD1>
                <CHARFIELD2>CS</CHARFIELD2>
            </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDK08_01>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000010</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268648</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7186T11101</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>1.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>250.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>200.000</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>GRM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>3.020</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>Aspiration Tube LATTISSIMA+ (50Pc) XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640154060593</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>85169000</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CH</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>95.13</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>1.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170822</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20271231</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>1.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>1.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>44.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>10.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000020</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012350651</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <LFIMG>56.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>218.400</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>217.280</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>1563.184</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>Case Corr NESPRS 250Caps 20PcN1XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630039622299</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48191000</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CH</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>405.46</GRWRT>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>56.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>56.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>56.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>14.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000030</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012302120</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7242T182M</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>7.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>9.590</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>8.400</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>29.400</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Sugar Sachet 1.2kg (300pc) N1 XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630030392412</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>17019990</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>NL</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>16.82</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>7.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170830</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20190830</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>7.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>7.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>30.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>11.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000040</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000040</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268362</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <LFIMG>0.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>0.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>0.000</NTGEW>
                    <VOLUM>0.000</VOLUM>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Pro DspbPapCup 40(55x175ml/6oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640145295027</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48236910</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>70.25</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>0.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>2.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>0.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>900001</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268362</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7212T145NA</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>1.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>12.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>11.600</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>91.210</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Pro DspbPapCup 40(55x175ml/6oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640145295027</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48236910</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>1.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170731</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20270731</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>2.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>1.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>900002</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268362</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7218T145NA</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>1.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>12.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>11.600</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>91.210</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Pro DspbPapCup 40(55x175ml/6oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640145295027</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48236910</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>1.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170806</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20271231</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>2.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>1.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000050</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000050</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268443</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>6363T145NA</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>1.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>6.120</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>6.120</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>88.510</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS TakeAwayCupLid36(50x350ml/12oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630030309182</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>39235090</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>44.09</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>1.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170629</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20271231</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>1.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>1.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>3.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>6.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000060</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000060</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268357</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7125T145NA</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>2.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>22.800</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>20.844</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>151.160</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Pro DspbPapCup 54(55x100ml/4oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640145295003</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48236990</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>70.71</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>2.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170719</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20271231</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>2.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>2.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>5.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000070</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000070</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268440</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>6360T145NA</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>1.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>2.520</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>2.400</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>34.130</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Take AwayCupLid24(50x100ml/4oz)XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630030309120</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>39235090</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>16.82</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>1.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170629</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20271231</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>1.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>1.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>8.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>6.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000080</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000080</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012346813</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>0000226876</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>192.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>345.600</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>341.760</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>2508.864</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Case Corr Carton 100Caps 20Pc XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630039622237</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48191000</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CH</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>769.01</GRWRT>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>192.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20171012</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20181010</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>192.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>192.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>6.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>16.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000090</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000090</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012346816</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <LFIMG>60.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>258.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>256.800</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>1946.280</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Case Corr Carton 300Caps 20Pc XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7630039622312</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>48191000</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CH</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>536.09</GRWRT>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>60.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>60.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>60.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>15.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
            <E1EDP07 SEGMENT="1">
                <BSTNK>LDP5877367</BSTNK>
                <POSEX>000100</POSEX>
                <E1EDP09 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0820046682</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000100</POSNR>
                    <MATNR>000000000012268003</MATNR>
                    <WERKS>8819</WERKS>
                    <LGORT>0001</LGORT>
                    <CHARG>7206T158M3</CHARG>
                    <LFIMG>7.000</LFIMG>
                    <VRKME>CS</VRKME>
                    <BTGEW>42.000</BTGEW>
                    <NTGEW>30.240</NTGEW>
                    <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
                    <VOLUM>417.970</VOLUM>
                    <VOLEH>DMQ</VOLEH>
                    <ARKTX>NESPRS Recycling Bin (6Pc) XI</ARKTX>
                    <EANNR>7640128875529</EANNR>
                    <STAWN>39249000</STAWN>
                    <EXART>1</EXART>
                    <HERKL>CN</HERKL>
                    <GRWRT>490.76</GRWRT>
                    <DOKPF>X</DOKPF>
                    <ABRDT>00000000</ABRDT>
                    <_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01 SEGMENT="1">
                        <ORDQTY>7.000</ORDQTY>
                        <ORDUNIT>CS</ORDUNIT>
                        <QPRODDAT>20170721</QPRODDAT>
                        <VFDAT>20270721</VFDAT>
                        <QTYFIELD1>7.000</QTYFIELD1>
                        <UOMFIELD1>CS</UOMFIELD1>
                        <QTYFIELD2>7.000</QTYFIELD2>
                        <UOMFIELD2>CS</UOMFIELD2>
                    </_-GLB_-OGT_E1EDP09_01>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>CSPERLAY</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>4.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                    <_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05 SEGMENT="1">
                        <QUALIFIER>LAYPERPAL</QUALIFIER>
                        <FIELDVAL1>5.000</FIELDVAL1>
                    </_-GLB_-RGT_DYN_SEG_05>
                </E1EDP09>
            </E1EDP07>
        </E1EDK08>
        <E1EDS02 SEGMENT="1">
            <SUMID>001</SUMID>
            <SUMME>65</SUMME>
        </E1EDS02>
    </IDOC>
</_-GLB_-OGTX_DESADV01_CUST_ASN>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You xml is not valid. In the example last tag doesn't match first tag.
2) Oracle has dedicated data type to support xml data (xmltype). One of xmltype constructor accept blob as parameter. But blob data has to be valid and well-formatted xml document.

`select xmltype(blob_column, charset_encoding ) from your_table.`

charset_encoding = 1 = USASCII but you have to find out proper encoding

3) To extract values from xml you can use xmltable.

```
 select distinct mantr from NES.WLI_DB t,
  xmltable('//MATNR' passing xmltype(t.DATA_VALUE,1) 
   columns mantr varchar2(1000) path 'text()')
   where t.id = '0000000331756259';
```

Comment: Will try your suggestion:)

Comment: i tried as below but got error
select DISTINCT MATNR  from NES.WLI_DB t, xmltable('//MATNR' passing xmltype(t.DATA_VALUE,1) 
COLUMNS MATNR varchar2(1000) path 'text()') where t.id = '0000000331756259-E9APRR3103' ;



Error:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'M'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 283
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: `Check if the document to be parsed is valid` try to do this. `select xmltype(data_value,1) from wli_db`

Comment: `select xmltype(data_value,1) from NES.WLI_DB where ID = '0000000331756259';`

-got same error as above.

Earlier, i used to use below query if have to run through specific blob and search for specific item.

Now, i am trying to pull certain values from that blob data but unsuccessful:(


`select * from NES.WLI_DB where ID = '1234' and dbms_lob.instr(data_value, utl_raw.CAST_TO_RAW('<ORGID>TA</ORGID></'), 1, 1) > 0;`